# Brightcove video events not firing on tablet devices

Tags: jquery, mobile, video, tablet, brightcove

I seem to be having an issue using the Brightcove video player events on tablet devices. The code that I have works great on desktop browsers but on tablets, the events themselves don't fire (my console log messages don't show up).

Am I missing something or doing something incorrectly? Here's a test link I've made live to see the entire document's code:  http://sql.bot.nu/bcove.html  -  notice the console shows the events on desktop browsers but my Android tablet tends to be silent and based on the responses I'm getting from the client, other tablets have the same issue.

```
// Initialize
var player, exp, bcExp, modExp, modCue, modVid, phead, pbtn, pos, dur, full, vol;

function onTemplateLoaded(pPlayer) {
  console.log('template loaded');

  // Setup
  player = bcPlayer.getPlayer(pPlayer);
  exp = player.getModule(APIModules.EXPERIENCE);
  bcExp = brightcove.getExperience(pPlayer);

  // Add event listener for template ready
  exp.addEventListener(BCExperienceEvent.TEMPLATE_READY, onTemplateReady); 

  // Get module references
  modExp = bcExp.getModule(APIModules.EXPERIENCE);
  modCue = bcExp.getModule(APIModules.CUE_POINTS);
  modVid = bcExp.getModule(APIModules.VIDEO_PLAYER);

  // Add event listener for content loaded
  modExp.addEventListener(BCExperienceEvent.CONTENT_LOAD, onContentLoad);
}

function onContentLoad(evt) {
  console.log('content loaded');

  // Create cookie if we don't have one
  if($.cookie(seekerCookie) == null){
    $.cookie(seekerCookie, 0, { expires: 3 });
  }

  // Seek to second stored in cookie
  seek($.cookie(seekerCookie));

  // Enable our continue button if the completed cookie has been set
  if($.cookie(completeCookie)==1) {
    $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled').removeClass("buttondisabled").addClass("button");
  }
}

function onTemplateReady(e) {
  console.log('template ready');

  // Remove template ready event and setup video complete event
  exp.removeEventListener(BCExperienceEvent.TEMPLATE_READY, onTemplateReady);
  video = player.getModule(APIModules.VIDEO_PLAYER);
  video.addEventListener(BCMediaEvent.COMPLETE, onComplete);

  // Set player elements
  phead = exp.find('#playhead')
  pbtn = exp.find('#playButton')
  pos = exp.find('#positionLabel')
  dur = exp.find('#durationLabel')
  full = exp.find('#fullscreenButton')
  vol = exp.find('#volumeButton')

  // Hide and show parts of the player
  phead.setVisible(false);
  pbtn.setVisible(true);
  pos.setVisible(true);
  dur.setVisible(true);
  full.setVisible(true);
  vol.setVisible(true);
}

function onComplete(e) {
  console.log('video completed');

  // Show player head
  phead.setVisible(true);

  // Enable submit button
  $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('buttondisabled').addClass('button');

  // Set the completed cookie
  if($.cookie(completeCookie) != 1){
    $.cookie(completeCookie, 1, { expires: 3 });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two versions of Brightcove's player API: the "Flash only player API" which only works with the Flash player, and the "smart player API" that works with both the Flash and HTML players.

Your code is using the flash only API, so won't work on tablets which use the HTML player.

Docs on the smart player api are at http://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/smart-player-api/index.html

Comment: Hey, thanks very much for your response. I'm a bit new to Brightcove and this code was inherited. The API docs you've pointed me to will work great. Cheers!